# WP-Admin edit.php & post.php slowdown after import of 10k users

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, wp-admin, users, author

**Situation**:

- Clean wordpress install
- No plugins
- VPS server 5.2ghz / 4gb RAM (Default Directadmin)
- Import of 10k users

**Problem**:

- WP-Admin edit.php and post.php take >4sec to load.
- A custom post type without the 'Author' support loads quickly

**What I tried**:

- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/28160, didn't work

**Question**:

- What to do to get it fast again?

Comment: Have you debug info to understand which part of the page loading is the culprit?

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

Had a custom author drop down function that causes a large query loop.

```
add_filter('wp_dropdown_users', 'cust_dropdown_users');
function cust_dropdown_users($output)
{
    $users = get_users();

    $output = "<select id=\"post_author_override\" name=\"post_author_override\" class=\"\">";

    //Leave the admin in the list
    $output .= "<option value=\"1\">Admin</option>";
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $sel = ($GLOBALS['post']->post_author == $user->ID) ? "selected='selected'" : '';
        $output .= '<option value="' . $user->ID . '"' . $sel . '>' . $user->user_login . ' (' . $user->user_email . ')</option>';
    }
    $output .= "</select>";

    return $output;
}
```

Now trying to find a better way to select different authors (feel free to suggest!).